# Why are my VSPackage menus missing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, plugins, vs-extensibility, vspackage

I have been going through the process of converting a VSPackage to Visual Studio 2010 that was originally written in Visual Studio 2005 and upgraded to Visual Studio 2008. See my other recent question: [Is it possible to use .ctc files in Visual Studio 2010 packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206661/is-it-possible-to-use-ctc-files-in-visual-studio-2010-packages)

After realising that my CTC files could no longer be used, I converted it to the VSCT format and I can run it successfully under the debugger in the experimental version of Visual Studio. However, when I try to register the package in the Registry for the actual version of Visual Studio, none of my menus show up (everything else works, so the plugin is registered).

This is the command that I used for regpkg to generate the .reg file which I then add to the Registry:

```
regpkg /codebase /regfile:Package.reg Package.dll
```

Is there anything else that I need to do when registering the package?

**Update:** It seems that running with the /register flag works. What is it doing differently from the registry file?

Thanks,
Alan